# How to get number of modified columns in ORACLE triggers?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I want to check if just one single column is modified in (After Update) trigger and other columns are not modified. 
how can I find count of updated columns in oracle triggers?

Thanks

Comment: Please paste some code here for everyone to verify

Comment: A trigger is fired when some event happens on the table you created it. Its nt possible to take count on how many columns the event took place. You can mention when the even should happen . Means you can mention the trigger to fire if some even happens on a column.

Comment: Why do you need this?